# How to disable or remove https cache?

Tags: asp.net, caching, web-config

I have a test website and a sales website. Their databases and files are different. I have gotten an ssl certificate for the domain and also for the subdomains.

test.website.com is redirecting to (for example) 'https://test.website.com/sale.aspx' but this test website gets main website's web.config info like:

- testDB is for test in web.config
- mainDB is for main in web.config

Data is being inserted into mainDB from the test.website.

Why do I have this problem?

Comment: You should use two different web.config as well different DB server.

Comment: well, in test files web.config it is testDB, in main files web.config is mainDB